# WPF: Problem with Hierarchy

Tags: wpf, hierarchy

I've noticed a problem I'm having depending on the Hierarchy of items. When I wan't to represent the items I have no idea how to put it's children in a manageable state.

Let's take a TreeView for example. When the window is loaded up I can take the model and put it into a view and as a source for the tree. However I seem to have no real control over the children. Only thing I can do is point to the children property of object and it shows up all real nice but what if I wan't to edit, sort and/or add a new item there I'm out of luck.

I can't really put the children into the view or a seperate collection to modify as they are only the property of the root element. Only way I can see at the moment is having the property return a ObservableCollection or a CollectionView and that has it's own problems as in no lazy loading for example.

How are you doing this, what is the proper way here and what am I missing?